# How to make SubTotals bold of DisplayTag table?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts, displaytag

I am creating display tag using below code

```
<display:table name="realtimereportcol" export="true" pagesize="25" sort="list" id="data" requestURI="" class="tablelist" decorator="org.displaytag.decorator.TotalTableDecorator">
        <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="false"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="false"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename">RealTimeIssuance_<%=oAppUtil.getSystemDateTime()%>.xls</display:setProperty>

        <display:column title="SUB_CHANNEL" sortable="true" property="sub_channel" group="1"></display:column>
        <display:column title="AGENT_NAMES" sortable="true" property="agent_names"></display:column>
        <display:column title="FTD" sortable="true" property="ftd" total="true" format="{0,number,#.##}"></display:column>
        <display:column title="MTD" sortable="true" property="mtd" total="true" format="{0,number,#.##}"></display:column>
        <display:column title="QTD" sortable="true" property="qtd" total="true"  format="{0,number,#.##}"></display:column>


</display:table>
```

I want to make sub totals bold,Just want to higlight the row which shows subtotal.Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can override method `addRowClass` for your table decorator.